# PDF reader for iOS with left to right paging support

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad, ios7

I am trying to develop an app for iOS in SWIFT ,which has a requirement to render Arabic PDF files and allow the user to read the PDF by swiping from left to right.I have tried a lot of libraries ,but didn't find a perfect way to do this.Can any please help me on this with any libraries or ideas.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you find pdf library support Arabic swiping from left to right ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi i just create a Swift project using https://github.com/vfr/Reader and you need to do following steps to convert this objective library in to swift:

- First you need to create a Bridge header file in to you swift project.
- Then you need to add vfr required file in to you project (that will be attached in my Sample code)
- Now you need to set import statement in to Bridge Header file

> `#ifndef Bridge_Header_h`
>
> `#define Bridge_Header_h`
>
> `#import "ReaderViewController.h"`
>
> `#endif /* Bridge_Header_h */`

- Add this Bridge file in to Project->target-> build Setting -> Objective-c Bridging Header and set Bridge file.
- Now Opne your project View Controller from that you wish to open pdf set Delegate file like:

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , ReaderViewControllerDelegate {
```

And it's View Controller ViewDidLoad code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let filepath = (NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Reader", ofType:"pdf"))! as String
        
        if let document = ReaderDocument.withDocumentFilePath(filepath, password: "")
        {
            let readerViewController: ReaderViewController = ReaderViewController(readerDocument: document)
            readerViewController.delegate = self
            // Set the ReaderViewController delegate to self
            self.navigationController!.pushViewController(readerViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

**Sample Code:** https://github.com/nitingohel/NGSwiftPdfReader

RealTime Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Is it possible to swipe from left to right instead of right to left to navigate between pages also with a paging effect.As mentioned i need to show a Arabic PDF which needs to swipe from  left to right

Answer (score 0):

try [M3PDFKIT](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13PDFKit) or [vfr](https://github.com/vfr/Reader). I use M3PDFKIT, can swipe to right and left

Comment: Hi Is it possible to swipe from left to right instead of right to left to navigate between pages also with a paging effect.As mentioned i need to show a Arabic PDF which needs to swipe from left to righ